# Ios app transfer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode, apple-id

I am developing an ios app for a client and would like to know that when I go for the $99 developer program I can post the app and get all the help but what about when I want to provide everything to the client will they have to get another apple id and sign up again for the $99 program or will they have to go for some other program and can the app be transferred from my account to theirs, it is going to be a free app, so if I manage it in the clients name is that okay. the app developed by should come as the "company's name"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transfer apps between developers' apple id. 
See [apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=6112013c):

> You can now transfer qualifying apps to another account — useful in
>   cases of an acquisition or asset purchase. When you transfer an app,
>   it will remain available on the App Store or Mac App Store, all
>   ratings and reviews will carry over, and users will continue to have
>   access to future updates.